# Python identify timestamp format from string

Tags: python, python-datetime

If I have a string of timestamp, is there some python library that can identify the format of timestamp and give me a `datetime` object? Example of a string is:

```
Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT
```

Can you also give an example of how it can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org). You can install it with [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil).

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt = parse('Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT')
print(dt)
print(type(dt))
```

Output

```
2016-01-16 07:50:17+00:00
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the package you have to install is "python-dateutil"

Comment: Hi. I was wondering if there was a way to obtain the format as a string, based on the input datetime value. For example:

input value = 1978-07-06
output value = '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: @TanviP: I think that you should search to see if a similar question has already been asked and, if you can't find one, ask it as a separate question. Perhaps looking at the `dateutils` source code might help.

Comment: @mhawke looked it up and couldn't find an answer. Asked a separate question 
 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893955/python-get-date-format-as-a-string-from-datetime64ns/50894059#50894059) but couldn't find an answer there either. Tried using the dateinfer package, but no luck. Could use some help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for parsing the string to a `datetime` type object.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_str = "Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT"
date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z')
print type(date_obj)
```

Output:

```
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: But it won't automatically identify the format of timestamp

Comment: yes. I think I misunderstood your question. You can  follow mhawke's answer. I shall keep the answer as it shows another way of doing the same thing.