# Python: Get date format as a string from datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I want to determine the date format of an input **datetime64[ns]** value, and obtain a str.

Example:

```
input value = 1978-07-06

output value = '%Y-%m-%d'
```

I've tried this but got stuck:

```
import dateutil.parser
from datetime import datetime

yourdate = dateutil.parser.parse(input)
datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(yourdate,'%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.
**Note: dateinfer gave me "No module named 'infer' " error**

Answer (score 0):

extract the date, from input using regular expression

```
import dateutil.parser
from datetime import datetime

input = '1978-07-06' # or - 06/07/1978
date_obj = dateutil.parser.parse(input)
date_string = date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: I'm looking for the strftime format as the output. Also the input date format could change to something like 06/07/1978. What I want to determine is the format based on any given input value ( 06/07/1978 or 1978-07-06). The datatype of input value is datetime64[ns] and not string